# Structural programming - What is this javascript pattern called? Is it okay using it?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

```
var contextMenu = {

    isVisible : false,

    open : function()
    {
            //some code here
    },

    close : function()
    {
            //some code here
    }   
}
```

I'm using this pattern heavily in my code. My application can be done using structural programming without need for classes/object instantiation.

First I used to write something like this:

```
var isContextMenuVisible : false,

function openContextMenu()
{
    //some code here
} 

function closeContextMenu()
{
    //some code here
}
```

Is this okay? What is this pattern called? What are the disadvantages?

**EDIT**: This is called as Singleton pattern

Btw, is it okay to use capitalized names for the object? Like `ContextMenu` instead of `contextMenu`? Would that be a proper convention?

Comment: It's not a pattern. It's just an object, it's just you using an objects in code. Why does everything have to be a "pattern"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton is a design pattern that forces the classes that implement it to offer only one point of access to them. Usually singletons are used for centralized management of internal or external resources and they provide a global point of access to themselves.
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript

Comment: It's not a singleton, it's an object.

Comment: @Raynos: I think the link clearly explains why it is called a singleton pattern.

Comment: Both of you are right. It is an object, from a prototype based view, and it is a singleton from a class based view.

Comment: @NebulaFox there is no "class based view" for JavaScript. Stop bringing these horrible patterns from other languages over.

Comment: @Raynos, I know there is no "class based view" in JavaScript, but you can create a "class based view". That is the power of JavaScript and prototype based systems.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to using that pattern, from what you were writing before, I would say that you were scoping. The advantages is your not creating global variables, which is always a good thing. The disadvantages is that you cannot access any of the values of the object until the entire object is created ( I get caught by this a lot ).

I am not sure this pattern has a name, but I suppose, it's object literal creation.

Comment: Thank you! I learn that this is a type of the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use classes|object instantiation, then best way is (from your samples):

```
function openContextMenu() {
  // some code here
  // you can use 'this' to point to current object
} 
function closeContextMenu() {
  // some code here
  // you can use 'this' to point to current object
}  
var contextMenu = {
    isVisible : false,
    open : openContextMenu,
    close : closeContextMenu   
};
var contextMenu2 = {
    isVisible : false,
    open : openContextMenu,
    close : closeContextMenu   
};
```

This allow you to create more than one object, and minimize memory usage.

---

But next is more ease:

```
function ConextMenu() {
}
ConextMenu.prototype.isVisible=false;
ConextMenu.prototype.open=function openContextMenu() {};
ConextMenu.prototype.close=function closeContextMenu() {};

var contextMenu = new ConextMenu;
var contextMenu2 = new ConextMenu; // or new ContextMenu()
```

Comment: Sorry, but there's going to be only one object. Btw, I never properly learned about `prototype` before. What would be the benefit of using `prototype` (your 2nd example) if there's only one object getting created?

Comment: In second example created two objects. One of uses of `prototype` in javascript is making classes|subclasses. Learn for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript And search for _prototype inheritance in javascript_